# Is my computer using too much RAM, possible faulty drivers?? My results using PoolMon

Tags: memory, drivers, bsod

Lately I have been getting Memory Management BSODs. I have 16GB of RAM, so i am unsure as to why this is happening. My SWAP usage would sometimes get high, but i am not sure if that is a related problem. I have used the  PoolMon tool and my results are below.

If there is a problem with my results and you know how to help, please do and explain to me how I may resolve this. Your help is much appreciated!

My Results with PoolMon:

- [NonPaged Results](https://9955575-371179652977548107.preview.editmysite.com/uploads/9/9/5/5/9955575/nonpaged.txt)
- [Paged Results](https://9955575-371179652977548107.preview.editmysite.com/uploads/9/9/5/5/9955575/paged.txt)

Comment: What operating system are you using?  (e.g.: Win XP/Vista/7?  32-bit or 64-bit?  Home/Pro/etc.?)  What is the Bugcheck code you get from the BSOD?  What are the values shown on the Performance tab of Task Manager (TaskMgr.exe)?  I have some experience troubleshooting such things, but I'd like some more preliminary info before I delve into studying those numbers too hard.

Comment: the poolmon values look ok. CM31 is used to load the registry hives of your user profile and this is always using the most memory. Share the dmp files from C:\windows\minidump so that we can debug them

Comment: 1. Memory management BSODs are not related to "running out of RAM", but rather to memory corruption by buggy kernel mode code (could be literally any driver in the system, including anti-malware products or other non-hardware "drivers") or by failing RAM. 2. What are you looking at that says "My SWAP usage would sometimes get high"?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro x64. I don't recall the bugcheck code. I also did get another BSOD: Special pool detection memory corruption. The performance tab in the task manager say that it is using 3.2/16.0 gb at idle committed: 3.9/37.7 gb; cached: 5.9 gb; Paged pool 610 MB; Non-paged pool: 176 MB; Harware reserved: 47.5 MB.

Comment: My minidump folder is empty ...

Comment: And also i am using a Rainmeter skin that tells me my System values: CPU, RAM, and SWAP usage. I recently adjusted the Virtual Memory paging file size to System managed size and that seemed to have brought SWAP usage down.

Comment: Well there's all kinds of reasons for BSODs.  Jamie gives some reasons.  [instructions to make a BSOD using the keyboard](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6529.how-to-manually-initiate-a-windows-stop-error-bsod-and-create-a-dump-file.aspx) show yet another.  You ought to look up the Bugcheck info so you're not guessing. Also, since this system is known-problematic, make sure (ahead of time, ) you'll get suitable dump files. [Some related info](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6302.windows-bugcheck-analysis.aspx#Understanding_the_Stop_Message)

Comment: have you disabled the pagefile? this file is needed to get dumps.

Comment: Okay, I think I have enabled it to allow to get dump files. And I don't believe that I have the pagefiles disabled. I have it setup to automatically manage paging file size for all drives... I will post them if I have did this properly next time i receive a blue screen.

Comment: Ok, I haven't recieved a blue screen in a while. I wonder if it was my computer getting too warm. I took my computer out of its confined area so that it could breathe and now I don't seem to be getting those blue screens. Is that a coincidence or was that the actually problem?

Comment: yes, overheating of CPU/GPU can cause crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I believe that it is safe for me to consider this question resolved. This seemed to have been all due to my computer overheating, since once I took it out of its confined space the BSODs stopped.